# Easier usage with markdown

Tags: featherlight.js

I am trying to use this from my markdown text. I want to show an image and clicking that will open in a lightbox. I am using something like below now:

```
<a href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spf13/hugo/master/docs/static/img/hugo-logo.png" data-featherlight="image">![Hugo](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spf13/hugo/master/docs/static/img/hugo-logo.png)</a>
```

Is there a way to achieve this without writing the url twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind featherlight on the `<img>` tag and use the `targetAttr` to get a similar effect.